# Braid Hair particles gives zig zag shapes in render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, hair

I am using the latest blender 2.81a 
I have hair particles with braid with a simple interpolation but it gives a result like below. how can this be avoided?

[image]

Comment: Good question. Consider to file a bug report on https://developer.blender.org/